# Duplicate parameter in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an issue regarding duplicate parameter in WebApi.

`http://localhost:xxxxx/api/getbook?UserId=7` in this API Controller I have one parameter string `UserId` and works fine but if i do something like that

`http://localhost:xxxxx/api/getbook?UserId=7?UserId=7` gets the result

So how to prevent duplicate parameter in API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1. There would be an & character between the parameters i.e. http://localhost:xxxxx/api/getbook?UserId=7&UserId=7
2. The first parameter of the same name will be used by default if you are taking a model in to a controller method

If you are keen to throw some error when you discover duplicate parameter names then you could do the following:

```
var queryParameters = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .GroupBy(k => k.Key)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .Select(q => q.Key)
                .ToList();
```

This will give you a `List<string>` of parameter names that appear more than once.

If you are interested in whether the parameter name and value combination is repeated (as in your example), then just `GroupBy(k => k)` instead and you will get a list of `KeyValuePair` to work with.

Comment: Thank you sir this is what i been looking for :D

Comment: Using action Context on executing action method we can Use this query right??

Comment: I tested this within a method in a controller. Somewhere else and you might need to use `HttpContext.Current.Request`. You could return a `BadRequest()` with a string or better still add a message to the `ModelState`.

Comment: Okay Thanks much appreciated :)